# How to graph data got from a web service?

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap, graph

I only have basic php knowledge and zero xml knowledge, my boss asks me to call the GetWesmData from this web service http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:1000/Service1.asmx?WSDL.

Luckily, through some google work, I found a set of code and it works

```
<?php

$wsdl = "http://10.246.199.35:1000/Service1.asmx?WSDL";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl);
$stock = "20130528"; //current date
$parameters= array("strDate_YYYYMMDD"=>$stock);
$value = $client->GetWesmData($parameters);     
$xml = $value->GetWesmDataResult;  

print "<pre>/n";
print_r($xml);  
print "</pre>";

?>
```

The output will be like this

```
/nstdClass Object
(
[WESMclass] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [output] => Success
                [STRdata_fld] => 5/24/2013 12:00:00 AM
                [STRtime_in_hours] => 1.000
                [STRLuzdem_dapel] => 6341.4
                [STRLuzdem_rtdel] => 6301.1
                [STRLuzdem_rtxel] => 6332.6
                [STRLuzwap_dapel] => 6332.6
                [STRLuzwap_rtdel] => 3120.23
                [STRLuzwap_rtxel] => 2577.72 
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [output] => Success
                [STRdata_fld] => 5/24/2013 12:00:00 AM
                [STRtime_in_hours] => 2.000
                [STRLuzdem_dapel] => 6130.7
                [STRLuzdem_rtdel] => 6094.4
                [STRLuzdem_rtxel] => 6107
                [STRLuzwap_dapel] => 6107
                [STRLuzwap_rtdel] => 3081.99
                [STRLuzwap_rtxel] => 2353.18 
            )
```

This data goes on up to 23.. What my boss wants is to display all 23 data of [STRLuzdem_dapel] in a line graph using php. I'm using wampserver.

I have found a graphing library called phpgraphlib.php in the internet and used it. Now I have this code for a line graph and it works well.

```
<?php
include('phpgraphlib.php'); //graph library
$graph = new PHPGraphLib(850,400);
$data = array("1"=>6341, "2"=>6130, "3"=>5991, "4"=>5883,
"5"=>5781, "6"=>5631, "7"=>5942, "8"=>6588, "9"=>7146,
"10"=>7486, "11"=>7800, "12"=>7709, "13"=>7719, "14"=>7970,
"15"=>7853, "16"=>7734, "17"=>7420, "18"=>7064, "19"=>7413,
"20"=>7318, "21"=>7289, "22"=>6867, "23"=>6670, );
$graph->addData($data);
$graph->setTitle('STRLuzdem_dapel');
$graph->setBars(false);
$graph->setLine(true);
$graph->setDataPoints(true);
$graph->setDataPointColor('maroon');
$graph->setDataValues(true);
$graph->setDataValueColor('maroon');
$graph->setGoalLine(0);
$graph->setGoalLineColor('red');
$graph->setXValuesHorizontal(true);
$graph->createGraph();
?>
```

But as you can see, I've manually entered the data.  What I want to do is to call the data from the web service, then get the values of all [STRLuzdem_dapel] and display it in a line graph. This is sort of a combination of the 2 set of codes I've shown you. I've tried combining it and changing some codes/variables to no avail. Can someone help me? Thanks